# Update except row of null in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have problem,when I tried to update except row of null in CakePHP.

Model -> Spot

column -> name,address

**[MySQL]**

id     / name                 / address

1   / Shibuya Bakery  /  Shibuya street 123

For example,there is database like the one above.

Then CakePHP got a name-value(Shibuya Cake Shop) from Android,and address-value is null.

Therefore I wanna update just name-column.

id = 1(post from Android)

```
public function update()
{
    if( isset($this->request->data["id"]) )
    {
        $id = intval($this->request->data["id"]);
        $fields = array( 'Spot.id' => $id );

        $data = array(  'Spot.name'     => "'".$this->request->data["name"]."'",
                        "Spot.address"      => "'".$this->request->data["address"]."'");
        $this->Spot->updateAll( $data,$fields );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to update just one field, just use saveField.

```
$this->Spot->id = $this->request->data['id'];
$this->Spot->saveField('name', $this->request->data['name']);
```

Don't use updateAll, as that is meant for updating multiple records, though technically you could add conditions to prevent it from doing so.  You're also passing incorrect arguments into updateAll. (See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-mixed-conditions for the correct way.)  If you want to update multiple fields at once on a single record, use save:

```
public function update()
{
    if( isset($this->request->data["id"]) )
    {
        $fields = array('name');
        if(!empty($this->request->data['address'])) array_push($fields, 'address');
        $this->Spot->save($this->request->data, true, $fields);
     }
 }
```

Read more on saving: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-your-data

Comment: Kai,thank you for attentive replay.
I don't know why save() function doesn't work as using update.But array_push function is so useful.Thanks.
Once again, and I read the text book properly